# HTML5 history API on iOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, html, google-chrome, html5-history

For testing purposes I want to populate the history with a number of entries. More precisely I want to add X items to kind of disable the backbutton of the browser, since even if the user is clicking X times, he will stay on the same page.

I'm doing this the following way:

```
(function (){
   for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
     history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);    
   }        
}());
```

So when the page is being loaded 10 elements of the current page are injected into the history. This approach works on all browsers that support the history API **except Chrome on iOS**!!!

Using the above code, Chrome on iOS (7 to 10) does some really weird things:

- It replaces the title in the tab with the url of the current page (so instead of showing "my great webpage" in the tab title, it shows "mygreatpage.com/samplepage1"
- long pressing the back button to check the entries, Chrome shows no additional added entries - every other browser shows 10 additional entries as intended by the code above

Safari and every other iOS browser do what I want them to. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may help: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=394296

Comment: It would be helpful to know the Chrome version you are testing against

Comment: always the latest stable of course

Answer (score 2):

For chrome on iOS native history.pushState is overidded by additional extension, if you `alert(history.pushState)` you can see it is not native code as we see on other browsers

see below polyfills may help you,

1. [HTML5-History-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API)
2. [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

Comment: what do you mean by "additional extension"?

Comment: Chrome ios overrides history.pushState function, it may not be the code from 'additional extension' but due to that we get above mentioned bug on chrome ios.